# how to write a custom control in c# to work with any windows text processor application?

Tags: c#, .net, user-controls

I am trying to write a custom control in c# using windows api which should interact with any windows text based application. for e.g. notepad

I had looked at tinyspell and it works like anything. can any one suggest how to get started?

also if u know how tinyspell would work, plz help me.

u can find tinyspell here http://www.tinyspell.m6.net/

Comment: not sure whether you choose the right language, I would have used Win32 or MFC

Comment: What kind of interaction do you have in mind? Cut/Copy/Paste, for example, works fine with a lot of controls and text processors, but that's not what you intent, or do you?

Comment: Priyank,

Language doesnt matter. i am willing to write in win32 or MFC. but i want to get started.

Comment: Brown,

I would like to add a dictionary to a editor of any kind. my app will stay in systray and if there is edit controls, then dictionary controls from my app should be invoked from any windows application

Answer (score 0):

Due to your comments, you are not tring to write a custom control but an application, and C# is not a must. I suggest having a look at [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) or [AutoIt V3](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/). I am pretty sure what you want can be done most easily with those scripting languages. And if you really need a C# application, you can use the Dll/Com control *AutoItX* included in AutoIt.

Comment: i already looked at that. that is not what i want. it cannot help me.

Comment: like i said, i want to implement tinyspell kind of.

Comment: @coder: If you don't provide us with more details, don't expect a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

I certainly agree with Doc Brown's statement that you are talking about writing an application, not a control. Also agree with his statement that you need to provide more information : exactly how does your application interact with these other applications that are handling (we assume) unformatted (one font, one style, one size) text ?

If you must do this in C#, you will need to use something like a "global hook" so the user can at any time, via some special keyboard activity, activate your application; for how to do this in C# see : [George Mamaladze's article "Processing Global Mouse and Keyboard Hooks in C#"](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx)

That also requires however, that your application be running at all times; normally if you want something running at all times, you might want your application to be a Windows Service. The "nitty gritty" of interacting with any one specific "raw" text-handling application could involve some API stuff, and/or use of the old 'SendKeys, and intimate knowledge of the application : my guess is you are not going to want to "go there."

Most likely you'll want to somehow use the clipboard as the "medium of exchange" between your application (or service) and the other applications. Lots of examples here on SO and on CodeProject about how to use the clipboard in .NET and/or drag and drop of selections in text between apps.

Good luck !

Comment: BillW,
thank you for your comments. i will give specific details soon